# WinSCP synchronizing files (Remote to Local Directory) from Azure VM

Tags: ssh, sync, sftp, azure, winscp

I am trying to follow [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndvEYOQLc4c) instruction regards to "SFTP - Windows Script to Automate Synchronize Remote to Local Directory using WinSCP".

When I ran a batch file, I got this message:

[image]

**I am not sure why it says "Cannot open file "C:\Windows\system32\SyncToLocalScript.txt".**

I ran this batch file (SyncToLocalScript.bat) inside this folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script=SyncToLocalScript.txt
pause
```

[image]

I placed this text file (SyncToLocalScript.txt) inside C:\Windows\System32.
Here are details of code.

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://ihcmirrdbuser:PasswordHere@ftpus.pointclickcare.com - 
hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 36:d1:fd:0e:c5:54:de:d7:3c:76:27:25:a3:4d:9f:64" 
synchronize local F:\FTP /SQL2016/Logs
exit
```

[image]

After that, nothing is happening (files are not synchronizing but getting message as indicated earlier).

I got the HostKeyInformation from WinSCP application, and I copied the second line of Server host key fingerprints - where it starts after **MD5** (please see below).
[image]

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Server host key fingerprints
SHA-256 = ssh-rsa 1024 yFTXpIc0fKp3JhQK5gIiauZ6GwPKE9pmJvcGSRo5nKs=
MD5 = ssh-rsa 1024 36:d1:fd:0e:c5:54:de:d7:3c:76:27:25:a3:4d:9f:64
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using Azure VM.

I am not sure whether it is anything to do with firewall or security issue with the VM.

Comment: [In the documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#hostkey) read the third sentence. I'm not sure why it outputs 'Host:' but it's not 'stuck' there -- after that it prompts 'winscp>' and it's waiting for _input_. BTW the author, Martin Prikryl, is a frequent participant here and several other Stacks so you might get a better response in a while.

Comment: It should be `/script=`, not `/script-`. + Next time please post code as a text, not as an image.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I edited the original post after I took your finding.

Comment: Your are running WinSCP with `C:\Windows\System32` as working directory, without specifying a path to the script file. So no wonder that WinSCP looks for the script in `C:\Windows\System32`. That's how files/paths in Windows (as any other common OS) work. (btw, putting the script to `Program Files` is not a good idea either).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl How does it automatically go to C:\Windows\System32? Do I fix in the "SyncToLocalScript.bat" where it points the script location, from (/script=SyncToLocalScript.txt) to something else? (like  /script="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\SyncToLocalScript.txt"  )

Comment: I do not know why your console starts in `C:\Windows\System32`. I believe it's the default path for Administrator console. But that's irrelevant to your question. Either change to the right directory before starting WinSCP or use a full path to the script, like in your last comment.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It worked! Fantastic. Thank you so much!